# Connecting to SQL server using integrated security

Tags: winforms, security, integrated

I would like to connect to an instance of SQL server over the network (or VPN) using Windows integrated security.

What steps exactly are necessary for me to accomplish this?
I am using Winforms.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a connection string from a config file and use this to create an SQL connection; a typical example for integrated security might be:

```
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=frosty;Password=flakes;
Initial Catalog=milkjug;
Data Source=supermarket
Integrated Security=True;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Where 'supermarket' is your fully qualified database name (or IP address); this can also include port numbers.

In your code a block like the following:

```
SqlClient.SqlConnection myConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
myConnection.Open();
```

The above is not tested and is from memory - should do the trick or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't believe this answers my question. The whole point is in not storing the user name and password on the client PC.

Comment: My bad - I combined two connection strings and forgot the final check.Just delete the User ID and Password items and that should do it.